# Copy installed extensions from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I've installed Visual Studio 2013 beside of Visual Studio 2012 - i have both versions installed so far. After i started 2013 i noticed that there were no extensions installed.

Is there a way to copy / adopt all installed Visual Studio 2012 extensions to Visual Studio 2013 or do i have to install them all again for 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic way to do it, sorry.